# Setting up eslint for testcafe in neovim

Tags: testing, electron, eslint, testcafe, neovim

Just started using testcafe and I'm trying to get eslint set up.
Here's the software and versions I'm using:

```
testcafe@1.8.1, eslint-plugin-testcafe@0.2.1, neovim@0.3.7, electron@7.1.9
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to have neovim stop with the red wiggly lines all over anything to do with testcafe?

I added:

```
"plugins": [
    "testcafe"
],
"extends": [
    "standard",
    "plugin:testcafe/recommended"
],
```

to the .eslintrc.json and

```
/* eslint-env testcafe */
```

to the test. Fabulously, the install and my first test worked fine and straight away!

Comment: Could you describe the issue in greater detail? It would help if you provide the error message you faced and a simple project where we can reproduce the problematic behavior.

Comment: The error behaviour is that neovim leaves red wiggly lines, as I said, no other error messages to report. I've put all the software versions and my config and config already so I don't know if there is any more info I can put. I just thought someone involved with testcafe or eslint would like to know or might now a simple step I've missed. It's not a biggy as I've stopped trying to use testcafe after it point blank refused to work in a simple test, but that's a different story. Thanks for the response though :)

Comment: This issue seems to be related to the eslint and neovim integration. Could you clarify if it works without eslint-plugin-testcafe?

Comment: The branch i was using for testcafe is now gone, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Let us know if you have any progress with the integration.